# How do I merge 2 dataframes?

Tags: r, merge

I have one `dataframe1` with a column containing firstnames and another `dataframe2` containing firstnames and the corresponding genders.

Now I want to add the gender-column of `dataframe2` into `dataframe1` but it doesn't seem to work with the following line:

`df2new <- merge(df1,df2,by.x="firstname",by.y ="gender")`

How can I merge these two dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dplyr package for this !

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe1 <- left_join(data_frame1,data_frame2,by="firstname")
```

Answer (score 0):

While Vincent's suggestion is great I wanted to provide another way using base R using something that seems to be similar to your data.

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Val","Sarah","Al"))
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("Joe","Jen","Kevin","Val","Sarah","Al"), 
                            gender = c("M","F","M","F","F","M"))

df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2)))
```